# Compiling a java file along with a package

Tags: java

I made a package which contains certain java files and I have a java program which uses that package in order to do work. The files within the package all have `package test;` as their first line. The file that uses the package imports it by `import test.*;`. I have a make file that looks like this:

```
....
CLASSES = \
    Client.java \
    test/A.java \
    test/B.java \
    ...
```

The makefile produces `*.class` files without any issues. The package is a "server" of sorts, and I need to start an instance of it before I start running the `Client`. When I say `java -cp . A config.properties` in the `./test` folder, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A (wrong name: test/A)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sample for the class plz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of (in the test folder)

```
java -cp . A
```

you need to go up one directory and

```
cd ..
java -cp . test.A
```

to get the `A` in the `test` package.